# Extraction of substrings from a string on the basis of multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, string

I have a string `str` from which multiple substrings are to be extracted.

```
str <- "Nucleotide transport and metabolism,Secondary metabolites biosynthesis, transport, and catabolism / Chromatin structure and dynamics,Coenzyme metabolism,"
```

The conditions for extraction are:

- Extract everything till the first occurrence of a `,` only if the next character is a capital letter
- If the character next to a `,` is not a capital letter, then proceed till

  - the next occurrence of `,` which is followed by a capital letter **OR**
  - the occurrence of  `/`   **OR**
  - the end of string

The output should look like this

```
>output
[1] "Nucleotide transport and metabolism"                           "Secondary metabolites biosynthesis, transport, and catabolism"
[3] "Chromatin structure and dynamics"                              "Coenzyme metabolism"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_split` from the `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)

str_split(str, ",(?=[:upper:])|\\s\\/\\s") %>% unlist() %>% gsub(",$", "", .)
[1] "Nucleotide transport and metabolism"                           
[2] "Secondary metabolites biosynthesis, transport, and catabolism"
[3] "Chromatin structure and dynamics"                             
[4] "Coenzyme metabolism,"
```

Comment: Thanks. The last substring however has a comma at the end. How to get rid of it?

Comment: We can use `gsub()` to get rid of the comma